# When to avoid doing Git rebase

Tags: git

I came across an [article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

At one point it explicitly and boldly mentions under subject *Perils of Rebasing* :-

> Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository.

The explanation is still unclear to me.

What are the situations where one has to use git merge/rebase over other(leaving out tidy history requirement) ?

Comment: The full quote is _"Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository **and people may have based work on them**."_ What is meant by that, is then explained below: _"When you rebase stuff, you’re abandoning existing commits and creating new ones that are similar but different. If you push commits somewhere and others pull them down and base work on them, and then you rewrite those commits with git rebase and push them up again, your collaborators will have to re-merge their work and things will get messy when you try to pull their work back into yours"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster I explicitly mentioned "The explanation is still unclear to me" and your response points out "What is meant by that, is then explained below". Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`git rebase` rewrites commit history.

So if you change the commit id by rebasing and someone else has an "old" commit id (for example if this commit id already exists in a master branch from where you've pulled your local repo) then you'll end up having 2 different commit ids for the same thing after rebasing. 
This is a situation that should be avoided as the article says.

In other words, make a rebase as long as the commits (sha1 commit ids) that you're about to change exist only in your local repository and don't alter sha1's that exist in remote repositories because someone might have pulled them and used to develop on top of.

Comment: That means as long as my local branch has no remote branch I can rebase freely...

Comment: Yes, sure. Even if you do have a remote branch but you're sure that no-one else has  pulled from it you can forcefully push the changes after rebase. The issue starts when other people get un-synced...

Comment: Getting error after resolving conflict in consequence of rebase :--- Applying: minor
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".

Comment: something went wrong during rebase process. type 'git status' to see the conflicts. Conflict means that there were two incompatible changes to one file that git cannot resolve by itself. So it asks for your help: resolve the conflicts (if you have modern IDEs they have a nice UI for this) and then continue rebase: git rebase --continue. If you want to return to "pre-rebase state" then type git rebase --abort